# getting additional data in passwordData when using SecKeychainFindGenericPassword in osx

Tags: macos, printing, passwords, keychain, garbage

I am using the following code to get password form the Keychain.

```
-(OSStatus *)getPasswordFromKeyChain:(NSString *)username{
    OSStatus status;

    const char *cService_name = "Mac App";
    UInt32 service_length = strlen(cService_name);

    const char *cUser_name = [username cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    UInt32 username_length = strlen(cUser_name);

    void *passwordData = nil; 
    SecKeychainItemRef itemRef = nil;
    UInt32 passwordLength = nil;

    status = SecKeychainFindGenericPassword(
                                    NULL,            // default keychain
                                    service_length,  // length of service name
                                    cService_name,    // service name
                                    username_length,// length of account name
                                    cUser_name,    // account name
                                    &passwordLength,  // length of password
                                    passwordData,        // pointer to password data
                                    NULL             // the item reference
                                    );
    NSLog(@"%s",passwordData);

    status = SecKeychainItemFreeContent (NULL,           //No attribute data to release
                                     passwordData);    //Release data buffer allocated by SecKeychainFindGenericPassword

    return status;
}
```

This works fine as I get success status.

But when I try to print the password I have obtained, I get the following result
- if the password is more then 6 characters, I see some garbage characters at the end of the actual password . e.g.

```
2012-11-17 12:01:28.731 MAC App[2042:303] sssssss`—~
```

If the password is less then or equal to 6 characters, I get the right password. e.g.

```
2012-11-17 12:01:33.244 MAC App[2042:303] ssssss
```

My question is why I am getting these garbage characters at the end? and how do I fix this issue? I need this password to use it in my application.

Answer (score 1):

I got my answer from [this link](http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/280680-convert-password-from-seckeychainfindgenericpassword-to-nsstring.html).

The reason for getting characters is explained in the link provided. I converted the password into NSString using the following code and that worked for me.

```
  NSString *tempStr = [[NSString alloc]initWithBytes:passwordData length:passwordLength encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSLog(@"%@",tempStr);
```